# Unit Testing ASP.NET MVC3 Applications (with NHibernate)

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I'm just starting my first MVC3 application, and I'm not sure how to unit-test it. I was planning to break out helper classes (static helpers, usually) into a separate assembly, as well as model classes, so that I could test them with NUnit.

So I'm OK on helper classes; but how do I test model classes (considering that they're annotated for NHibernate and tied to the database), and how can I test my views and controllers?

**What are the specific tools and techniques I need to test NHibernate-bound models, as well as ASP.NET views and controllers?** I'm not sure. NUnit only solves some of the problem.

**Edit:** Here's some samples of code -- I'm not on my dev machine right now, so I don't have real code to show-case.

- **Models:** Anything from the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/relations.html)
- **Controllers:** The standard HomeController from the [MVC3 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y38)
- **Views:** Any strongly-typed view (let's say Create) generated from the right-click context menu (Add > View)

Specific questions:

- How I can test saving models without actually saving to the main/production database
- Scope for testing views; should I simply test fields exist? What about validation error messages?
- Controllers: scope for testing. Should I test that actions touch and deform database data as expected (eg. /get/id gets that object; /delete/id deletes that object)?

Comment: Show an example of a code you would like to unit test. Currently your question is difficult to answer.

Comment: I don't have anything complicated (and I don't have ASP.NET MVC3 on this computer), so I've referenced links. Starter code is pretty much what I have (ActiveRecord/NHibernate for models, standard ASP.NET MVC3 views and controllers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get there by various kinds of tests, but you need to apply them wisely depending on what you are going to test:

- Use unit test to test your controllers, or your business logic, without hitting the database.
- Use integration testing by running on an in-memory database (which NHibernate supports and is easy to setup). You can make sure a scenario actually works, e.g. using a valid scenario, all the business logic is working, your controller pass the data to persistence mechanism and it goes correctly into the database.
- You can use UI Testing using frameworks such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) but only do that where really needed, because it is not easy as two previous types of tests, and would become hard to maintain and fragile.

It is a best practice to keep your view (UI) thin, and test other layers behind the UI, as testing the UI probably does not worth all the hassle.